# Null values are inserted in the foreign key fields with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a `Question` Entity and `Tag` entity with getter, setter methods and a `OneToMany` relationship from `question` to `tag` and a `OneToOne` relationship from `question` to `user`

```
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="body")
    private String body;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="date_created")
    private Date date_created;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="tag_id")
    private Tag tag;

    @Column(name="answer_count")
    private int answer_count;

    @Column(name="view_count")
    private int view_count;

    public Question() {

}
```

Tag entity

```
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="date_created")
    private Date date_created;

    public Tag() {

}
```

When I try to insert a question using Postman with the following details:

```
{
    "title": "stefanyyyxx",
    "body": "stefandoyee44",
    "date_created": "2019-02-27",
    "user_id" : 1,
    "tag_id": 1,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "view_count": 0
}
```

QuestionRepository.java:

```
@Override
public void save(Question theQuestion) {

    // get the current hibernate session
    Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    // save employee
    currentSession.saveOrUpdate(theQuestion);
}
```

Null values are being inserted for `user_id` and `tag_id` though I used `JoinColumn()`.

MySQL:

[image]

Comment: Do the `user` and `tag` objects inside your `theQuestion` object exist? Are they filled?

Comment: in DB schema are these fields nullable ..? and do you have records for user and tag with id 1 ?

Comment: @Nuthan Kumar the user_id and tag_id can be nullable in DB schema. I have records for user and tag with id 1

Comment: @ayrton Do I need to set the user tag objects instead of just passing the user_id and tag_id on a REST call as I used JoinColumn

Comment: can you try with  @OneToOne( mappedBy = "user_id")
   private User user;

Comment: try "user" : {"id":1},  instead of "user_id" : 1, and "tag": {"id":1}, instead of "tag_id": 1,

Comment: @imperezivan  got an exception `An immutable natural identifier of entity com.springbootangular.discussionforum.entity.User was altered from bhar@mail.com to null` for that

Comment: Try to use Jackson Mapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Karol Dowbecki Suggested,

convert the JSON to DTO object and use that DTO to get the `User`, `Tag` Entities from their respective *repositories*.

Finally create the Question entity object and store it.

**Question Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "body")
    private String body;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    private Set<Tag> tag;

    @Column(name = "answer_count")
    private int answerCount;

    @Column(name = "view_count")
    private int viewCount;

}
```

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

}
```

**Tag Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_created")
    private Date dateCreated;

}
```

**DTO Class**

```
public class QuestionDTO {

    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String body;

    private Date dateCreated;

    private Long user;

    private Long tag;

    private int answerCount;

    private int viewCount;
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    private QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TagRepository tagRepository;

    public void addQuestion(QuestionDTO dto) {
        Tag tag = null;
        User user = null;
        Question question = null;

        Set<Tag> tags = null;

        tag = tagRepository.findById(dto.getTag());

        tags = new HashSet<>();
        tags.add(tag);

        user = userRepository.findById(dto.getUser());

        question = new Question();
        question.setTag(tags);
        question.setUser(user);
        question.setId(dto.getId());
        question.setBody(dto.getBody());
        question.setTitle(dto.getTitle());
        question.setViewCount(dto.getViewCount());
        question.setAnswerCount(dto.getAnswerCount());
        question.setDateCreated(dto.getDateCreated());

        questionRepository.save(question);

    }
}
```

**NOTE** : 
The relation between `Question` and `Tag` are in `OneToMany` you have to use `Collection` type.

Comment: Woked like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch between JSON and `@Entity` structure. JSON contains numeric identifiers while the `@Entity` contains actual objects representing relationships. You most likely should introduce a separate DTO class to map this JSON while in `@Repository` you should load `User` and `Tag` objects based on their id or create new ones. You already have `CascadeType.ALL` so Hibernate will cascade the persist operation.

Generally the controller layer should be separate from repository layer unless you are doing something very, very simple. This helps to evolve the service without changing the API contract e.g. adding new columns for auditing changes. By exposing the `@Entity` as DTO you make your life harder down the road.

Comment: How to get the id from the JSON object and load the objects in teh repository? Can you provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add referencedColumnName in your Child Entity Foreign Key Column

```
referencedColumnName="your primaray key column name"
```

**EDIT:**

**referencedColumnName**

- The name of the column referenced by this foreign key column.
- When used with entity relationship mappings other than the cases
  described here, the referenced column is in the table of the target
  entity.
- When used with a unidirectional OneToMany foreign key mapping, the
  referenced column is in the table of the source entity.
- When used inside a JoinTable annotation, the referenced key column is
  in the entity table of the owning entity, or inverse entity if the
  join is part of the inverse join definition.
- When used in a CollectionTable mapping, the referenced column is in
  the table of the entity containing the collection.
- Default (only applies if single join column is being used): The same
  name as the primary key column of the referenced table.

Asset is Parent Entity and AssetDetails is Child Entity
Here I have taken OneToOne Relationship

**Asset.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="asset")
public class Asset {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="assetid")
    private BigInteger assetid;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "asset")
    @JsonBackReference
    private AssetDetails assetDetails;

     public AssetDetails getAssetDetails() {
        return assetDetails;
    }

    public void setAssetDetails(AssetDetails assetDetails) {
        this.assetDetails = assetDetails;
        assetDetails.setAsset(this);
    }

    public Asset(your fields, AssetDetails assetDetails) {
        super();
        // your fields
        this.assetDetails = assetDetails;
        this.assetDetails.setAsset(this);
    }

    public Asset() {
        super();
    }

    public BigInteger getAssetid() {
        return assetid;
    }

    public void setAssetid(BigInteger assetid) {
        this.assetid = assetid;
    }
}
```

**AssetDetails.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="assetDetails")
public class AssetDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private BigInteger assetdetailid;

    @JoinColumn(name = "assetid",nullable = false, updatable = false,referencedColumnName="assetid")
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Asset asset;

    public Asset getAsset() {
        return asset;
    }

    public void setAsset(Asset asset) {
        this.asset = asset;
    }

    public AssetDetails(your fields,Asset asset) {
        super();
        //your fields
        this.asset = asset;
    }   
}
```